# Как получить данные из 2 элемента Json?

Tags: android, json

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "data":{
       "215":{},
       "248":{},
       "252":{}
    }
}
```

Как получить 2 элемент?

`json.getJsonObject("data")`. А дальше что? Тут проблема в том, что я по сути не знаю названия объектов. Таких как `215`, `248`, `252`. На то он и запрос, как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что есть второй элемент не совсем понятно, у объектов порядок свойств может быть произвольным. А получить все ключи можно так:

```
JsonObject data = json.getJsonObject("data");
Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = data.entrySet();
for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry: entries) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());//"215","248","252"
}
```

...и, например, взять второй элемент.
А вообще, логичным выглядел бы json вида:

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "data":[
       {"id":"215","object":{}},
       {"id":"248", "object":{}},
       {"id":"252", "object":{}}
    ]
}
```

или id внутри object:

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "data":[
       {"id":"215",...},
       {"id":"248",...},
       {"id":"252",...}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Знаю, говорил прогеру, он говорил что типо я не прав и так как он написал правильнее), что за люди нынче пошли) лишь бы доказывать свою неправоту, даже если другие правы

Answer (score 1):

Опишите класс получаемого объекта и дессериализуйте его:

```
gson.fromJson(jsonString, Type.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае доступ можно получить только по ключу, т.к. тип у `data` - `JsonObject`, а не `JsonArray`.

Comment: А ключа в данном коде нету верно?
215 это значение.

Выходит что Json не правильно составлен?

Comment: @xTIGRx ```215``` это как раз и есть ключ. Вообще немного странно выглядит этот ```JSON```. Если это приходит из общедоступного ```API```, то дайте ссылку, может быть это что-то прояснит.

Comment: @temp, да я знаю что код странный), но так прогер говорит что типо так все делают. из объекта трудно получить тупо значение.

для таких целей в Json придумали массивы

Comment: @xTIGRx массивы имею другую структуру